# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"length"' can't be used to index type '{}'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
 function getLength<T>(arg: T): number {
 if (!arg.hasOwnProperty("length")) {
   return 0;
 }
 return arg["length"];
}
```

Here I am not able to access the value through bracket notation, this works in javascript but typescript is giving me issues on this.

[image]

This is the error in terminal thats running ts-node-dev

Comment: Which typescript version are you using? It compiles on 4.6.3.

Comment: Well to be fair most things can compile with the right options in the tsconfig ;) - Putting this in the playground yields two errors on 4.6.2

Comment: To satisfy the compiler, does `getLength<T extends { [key: PropertyKey]: unknown }>(arg: T): number` work for you?

Comment: I upgraded to typescript v^4.6.3 still the same, is this a tsconfig issue?

Comment: @NoobLife it does not compile in my setup, I upgraded to typescript ^4.6.3

Answer (score 2):

[Using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

```
type HasLength = { length: number };

function hasLength(arg: any): arg is HasLength {
  return (arg as HasLength).length !== undefined;
}

function getLength<T>(arg: T): number {
  if (arg && hasLength(arg)) {
    return arg.length;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

console.log(getLength(3)); //0
console.log(getLength("333")); //3
console.log(getLength({ "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3 })); //0
console.log(getLength({ "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, length: 3 })); //3
console.log(getLength([1, 2, 3])); //3
console.log(getLength(true)); //0
console.log(getLength(undefined)); //0
console.log(getLength(null)); //0
```

The reason for using `arg && hasLength(arg)` instead of `hasLength(arg)` is that calling `undefined.length` or `null.length` will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

in your function you're using a generic type named `T` and by default, it's defined as `any`, and `any` does not have a `length` property so you should extend your type so it should be defined in your generic like the following:

```js
function getLength<T extends { length?: number, [key: string]: any }>(arg: T): number {
    if (typeof arg.length === 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }
    return arg["length"];
}
console.log(getLength([1, 3, 4])) // --> 3
console.log(getLength({ length: 4 })) // --> 4
console.log(getLength({ a: 1 })) // --> 0
```

Comment: Not sure whether its Ok or not for the OP, but `getLength({a: 30})` doesn't work.

Comment: @NalinRanjan oh, so the question is how to pass any argument and have a fallback for types that don't have a length property?

Comment: I'm not sure of that. We will have to ask that to the OP.

Comment: Yes this works but I'm not clear about the syntax, can you elaborate the <T extends ..> part, what is [key: string] why is it in brackets? The code works as expected so thanks for that.

Comment: ``` console.log(getLength<number>(22));
console.log(getLength("howdy there"));``` I want to supply args in this manner, with the code above it always must be an object. What needs to be changed?